# Runtime error when searching list

Tags: c, linked-list, runtime-error

me again. My searching program is almost finished. However, there is a runtime error during  searching in the single linked-list. It only happens when I search with range. Thanks for helping. Here is the related code.

```
int casearchrange(LIST *list,STUDENT **pPre,STUDENT **pLoc,int upper,int lower){
    *pLoc = list->head;
    for (;*pLoc!=NULL && lower>(*pLoc)->ca;){
        *pPre = *pLoc;
        *pLoc = (*pLoc)->next;
    }
    if (*pLoc==NULL)
        return 0;
    else {
        for (;(*pLoc)->ca<upper&&*pLoc!=NULL;)
            if ((*pLoc)->ca>=lower&&(*pLoc)->ca<=upper){
                printf("%s\n%d  | %-18s|  %0.1f  |  %0.1f",RESULT,(*pLoc)->sid,(*pLoc)->name,(*pLoc)->ca,(*pLoc)->exam);
                *pLoc=(*pLoc)->next;
            }
            fflush(stdin);getch();
            return 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. It will stop when the crash happens and you can exactly which line the problem is on, and also you can examine variables to see which one is the likely cause of the crash. The two likely causes is a `NULL` pointer, or a pointer that's not initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests in the line

```
for (;(*pLoc)->ca<upper&&*pLoc!=NULL;)
```

are the wrong way round.  You'll dereference `*pLoc` as part of the `(*pLoc)->ca<upper` test before checking for `*pLoc!=NULL`.  The fix is simply to swap the order of the tests

```
for (;*pLoc!=NULL && (*pLoc)->ca<upper;)
```